# How to become a researcher?

Tags: publications, research-process, independent-researcher, publishers

I would like to follow a line of investigation but I have some doubts. I'm mathematician and currently finishing my master's degree in Latin America. I know that I have a lot to learn to make impact articles, but I would like to start by publishing results from my point of view with alternate demonstrations or a different approach, and progressively improve. But I do not know where I can make those publications and have them seen internationally, I know some Latin American magazines but being in Spanish or Portuguese it is very difficult for it to become international. I like constructive criticism, so I am not afraid to publish something and know my mistakes either in editing or presentation, I want to continue improving. Perhaps this query is out of place on that website but I would like to know your point of view, since many here have gone through the same thing as me, and I would like you to share your experiences with me to continue improving.

I'm sorry about the tags but I didn't find a suitable one for this query.

Answer (score 5):

A PhD is the standard way to get trained in academic research. While that doesn't mean it is impossible to do good research without a PhD, my impression is that most people who think they can skip the training step have misled themselves. A PhD isn't just a title to hold, it's a mark of having completed this training program.

It's certainly possible to publish as a masters student, but you'll want to get input from a research advisor. Even "low impact" work is difficult to publish properly, and you can do damage to your reputation (or, at minimum, waste your own time) trying to do it yourself.

I would not advise trying to publish without a research advisor's assistance until you've successfully published several papers *with* assistance. A research advisor will be able to help you decide what appropriate venues there are for the work you're doing, and how to frame your work in a way that it will be interesting to other readers. If you're in mathematics, it seems even harder in that in many subfields research papers are extremely niche and there may be only one or two people in the entire world that are even remotely interested; it does not sound that you're at a point where you know how to find those two people, so you need additional support.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should start by looking at journals that publish the kinds of papers you expect to write.

Journals written in English are likely to be more widely  read than those in Spanish or Portuguese, and your English is clearly good enough for you to consider them.

I don't think you should worry about international visibility. The practice at putting your ideas on paper in a way that makes them attractive to the editor of your journal of choice is what you need now. You will get the criticism you need from the referees.